# Smack connection close during file upload via retrofit

Tags: php, android, apache, upload, smack

I'm developing an XMPP client on Android using Smack library and Ejabberd as my XMPP server.

so far everything is working good, but whenever Users start uploading large files and sending lots of messages rapidly, their connection got close from server.
I get following from debuger:

> connection Closed Error Parser got END_DOCUMENT event

uploading is handled via retrofit library

I checked Ejabberd config, so user are allowed to send messages rapidly and config of php upload server allows large files uploading.

also Ejabberd and php upload server are not in the same host.

I just can't get where the problem is, is it from smack, ejabberd or even android itself.